# UIWebView w/ Rails push notifications

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise, uiwebview

I have got a web app written in Rails running on Heroku, using Devise as the authentication system. It is fully responsive and works well when pinned to Homescreen.

However I would like to put it in as a native iOS app, using UIWebView. In order to get more out of the experience, I would like to add push notifications.

What is the best way to call a Push notification, without breaking the webapp version?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: [Pusher](https://pusher.com/) is something to look at